# Photocell comparator circuit using LM339

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

[image]

How to prove this mathematically?

Comment: There's nothing to prove; it's just a statement.

Comment: Do you understand how the circuit works? What does the LM339 do? To make the LED light up, the output of the LM339 needs to have a ??? voltage. When will the LM339 output a low voltage? What needs to happen to the input voltages?

Comment: Understand that the photoresistor has resistance between its terminals that varies *inversely* with light...a dark photoresistor has very high resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the statement "R1 = 3x R2" applies when the LDR is illuminated.

If R1 = 3x R2 then the voltages at the inverting and non-inverting inputs of the comparator will be 3V and 6V respectively.

If the illumination is normal room or daylight illumination, when LDR is in the dark the resistance will increase by at least an order of magnitude, so those voltages will be more like 10V and 6V respectively.

Have a look at the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2901.pdf?ts=1596917091302&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) to see how the LM339 comparator behaves under those two conditions. Note also the section 9.2.2.1 regarding input range for what happens if the LDR is so high resistance that the inverting input voltage exceeds 10 or 10.5V.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write an equation for the voltage at the inverting input.
2. Write an equation for the voltage at the non-inverting input
3. Write a conditional equation relating the two input equations to the output state.

Answer (score -1):

R1 should be adjustable.
When LDR in the dark, R2 increase as voltage at inverting input of lm339.
If inverting input's voltage greater that positive input the outout is low state current can pass through led and turn it on.

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question which was asked